# wordpress wp_get_archives output change with preg_replace

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

good morning boys and girls...can someone point me to the right direction, please.

i want to replace my php-echo-output
`JUNE 29, 2009–JULY 5, 2009`
with just plain text: `last week`

```
<?php
ob_start();
wp_get_archives('type=weekly&limit=1');
$wklyarchives = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$wklyarchives = preg_replace('%\&\#8211\;[a-zA-Z0-9, ]*\</a\>%s', 'last week</a>', $wklyarchives);
echo $wklyarchives;
?>
```

this preg_replace replaces just the 2nd part, so my output is now `JUNE 29, 2009last week`
this preg makes me crazy...

Answer (score 2):

You are only matching the dash and the part after it, so that's exactly what is getting replaced. If you add the same character class *before* the dash, like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9, ]%\&\#8211\;[a-zA-Z0-9, ]
```

it should work (depending on what `$wklyarchives` contains even before the 'JUNE 29' part; you might have to make sure you don't mach *too much*).

Comment: $wklyarchives = preg_replace('[a-zA-Z0-9, ]%\&\#8211\;[a-zA-Z0-9, ]*\</a\>%s', 'last week</a>', $wklyarchives);

thanx for your answer...i dont know why, but it don't work.

Comment: What is the *exact* content of $wklyarchives before the replacing?

Comment: i got this output:
JUNE 29, 2009–JULY 5, 2009

Comment: The dash between 2009 and JULY: Is that a normal dash, an em dash, an en dash, an escaped one? The one you're posting is a regular dash, but from your regex it seems it should be an escaped en dash.

Comment: Then why is this: %\&\#8211\; in your regex?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, tried this with WordPress, worked fine:

```
'/[a-z0-9,]+ [0-9,]+ [0-9]+.?[a-z0-9,]+ [0-9,]+ [0-9]+/iu'
```

Remember, do not use output buffering with wp_get_archives. Use echo=0:

```
$wklyarchives = wp_get_archives("type=weekly&limit=1&echo=0");
```

Good luck.